# Cannot Access Heroku Dashboard

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to access the Heroku website now and it's not responding.

> API Unavailable

I can't even update my application through CLI.

How soon this will be fix?

Comment: Maybe you should write to their support, I'll vote to close this question since it does not concern programming...

Comment: Thanks! Before I posted here I already contacted their support. Hoping that someone from their support team will also notice since I tag it correctly and maybe someone has also a similar problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to the process of software development nor belongs on any other of the Stack Overflow sites. It is more appropriate to be answered as part of Heroku Customer Support.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku was affected by the DDOS attacks made to DynDNS. Check [Heroku Status](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/965) for more info